# Почему исполняемый файл Go много больше, чем C?

Tags: golang

Например.

hi.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("C\n");
}
```

hi.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go")
}
```

Собираем:

```
$ gcc -o c hi.c
$ 8g hi.go && 8l -o go hi.8
```

Получаем:

```
$ ls -l

  7088 2010-10-29 21:33 c*
953840 2010-10-29 21:33 go*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ вполне очевиден: программа на Го тянет за собой большой и толстый пакет main, тогда как программа на Си тянет лишь stdio

Comment: Да, так оно и есть. Пакет main реально может много больше, чем просто простой вывод. Плюс еще управление памятью, динамические типы, рефлексия и, возможно, что-то еще, чего нет в stdio.