# Почему так много весят exe файлы

Tags: golang

Почему так много весят exe файлы в go. Простой код выдал 2.165 kb,
а в gcc на с 29 kb.

Comment: там запакован сам golang

Comment: Подключи либу к Си статически, будет примерно та же картина.

Comment: https://science.raphael.poss.name/go-executable-size-visualization-with-d3.html

Comment: Можно ощутимо уменьшить размер бинарного файла если удалить из него дебаг информацию `strip <binary_file>` но даже в таком случае бинарник на го будет весить на порядок больше из-за статической линковки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему исполняемый файл Go много больше, чем C?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-go-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-c)